# How to extend/add a Bouncycastle digest algorithm for CMS?

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

With Java I want to cryptographically sign given `byte[] hash` with RSA and return `byte[] signature` in the [Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_Message_Syntax) format.

I am using the [Bouncycastle Java API (BC)](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) for this purpose and face the problem of the not existing `NONEwithRSA` signature type. (`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown signature type requested: NONEWITHRSA`).

I, unfortunately, cannot change the input nor the required output format so I am required to extend/add to the existing BC algorithm so that I can use `NONEwithRSA` instead of all the other existing (e.g. `SHA256withRSA`). How do I do this? I have not found any example in the BC documentation.

#### My desired usage would be similar to this

```
byte[] doSigningCMS(byte[] data, X509Certificate cert, PrivateKey key) throws Exception {

    CMSSignedDataGenerator signGen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
    CMSTypedData content = new CMSProcessableByteArray(data);

    ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("NONEwithRSA").build(key);

    DigestCalculatorProvider dcp = new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build();

    signGen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(dcp).build(signer, cert));

    return signGen.generate(content, false).getEncoded();
}
```

#### What I have tried so far

- Adding my own provider for the JCA with "copying" a bunch of BC code and "fake" `SHA256withRSA` to basically return a `NoneDigest` instead of `SHA256Digest`. But this seems to be very wrong.
- Adding my own algorithm to BC with `((BouncyCastleProvider) Security.getProvider("BC")).addAlgorithm(ALG_ALIAS, NoneDigest.class.getName())` which does not seem to work (algorithm is not found)

I hope for some advice and guidance to do this (if even possible) *"the right way"*. Thanks.

Comment: Where is the specification for the "NoneWithRSA" signature algorithm? I would be tempted to customize JcaContentSignerBuilder to start with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"NoneWithRSA" is a RSA digital signature without adding the OID of the digest algorithm. The cryptographic provider does not make the digest either. Basically it is a PKCS#1_v15 encryption with the private key.

You can see how it works in this OpenJDK test https://github.com/ddopson/openjdk-test/blob/master/java/security/Signature/NONEwithRSA.java

Since Bouncycastle seems does not support it, I think you can supply your own [ContentSigner](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/operator/ContentSigner.html) implementation using the default provider instead of using `JcaContentSignerBuilder`

It is supposed that the input data is already hashed, so if you are doing a PKCS#1 signature, I think you need to provide the signature algorithm. Looking at the [RFC3477](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt) it depends on the hash algorithm used.

> A.2.4 RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5
>
> The object identifier for RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 shall be one of the
>      following.  The choice of OID depends on the choice of hash
>      algorithm: MD2, MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256, SHA-384, or SHA-512.

---

```
String sigAlgo = "SHA256WithRSAEncryption"; // "SHA256WithRSAEncryption" for SHA256, "SHA1WithRSAEncryption" for SHA1, etc.
ContentSigner signer = new CustomContentSigner(key, sigAlgo );
```

---

```
public class CustomContentSigner implements ContentSigner {

    private AlgorithmIdentifier algorithmIdentifier;
    private Signature signature;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream;

    public CustomContentSigner(PrivateKey privateKey, String sigAlgo) {
        //Utils.throwIfNull(privateKey, sigAlgo);
       this.algorithmIdentifier = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find(sigAlgo);

        try {
            this.outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            this.signature = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA");
            this.signature.initSign(privateKey);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException gse) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(gse.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public AlgorithmIdentifier getAlgorithmIdentifier() {
        return algorithmIdentifier;
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
        return outputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getSignature() {
        try {
            signature.update(outputStream.toByteArray());
            return signature.sign();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException gse) {
            gse.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I do not know if it will work but you can try it

Comment: Thanks for your hint, a `CustomContentSigner` seem to be a good start. However, I still have the problem of the `DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder` not finding the (in BC not existing) `NONEwithRSA` algorithm. I do not see a way of providing that algorithm to BC.

Comment: I think you should supply the signatureAlgorithm according to the digest algorithm you applied to your data before signing it with "NONEwithRSA". See the updated answer

Comment: @fdomig, did you finally solve the issue?. I am curious if this can really work

Comment: Unfortunately not yet.

Comment: I think I found a solution that works for me. But I unfortunately use the `RSABlindEngine` to create my Signature and create the CMS-structure afterwards in a manual step. But you lead me to the right direction and therefore I accept your answer. Thanks.